# Why are my items not showing in my cart? Django

Tags: python, django

Can someone tell me why my products are not showing up on my cart? They are being added to the database but somehow not showing up on my page.
I will attach some screenshots of my project:
These are the important views:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUat8.png)

This is the form used to add the products to cart:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyiTQ.png)

And this is the cart.html, where nothing shows up:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MffM.png)

This shows up once I open the cart on the browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPvQO.png)

Comment: Please  provide code instead of screenshot

Comment: Please paste code in the question by editing.